# Qt: checkbox single click not working

Tags: qt, checkbox, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I'm playing around with QtQuick in **Qt 5.9** and I encountered a strange issue.
When I created two `Tumblers` and a `CheckBox` in QML everything was working fine.

But when I created an event handler for a `id: secondTumbler` which manipulates `testCheckBox.checked` status the `CheckBox` started to act in a strange way.

When I launch the app and firstly scroll around any tumbler and then click the `CheckBox` it will not check. The second click will eventually check it but that is a strange behavior.

The only thing I wrote is the below code in the main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Tumbler {
        id: firstTumbler
        model: 10
        anchors.left: parent.left
    }

    Tumbler {
        id: secondTumbler
        model: 10
        anchors.right: parent.right

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                testCheckBox.checked = false
        }
    }

    CheckBox {
        id: testCheckBox
        anchors.left: firstTumbler.right

        onCheckedChanged: {
            if(testCheckBox.checked == true)
            {
                secondTumbler.currentIndex = firstTumbler.currentIndex
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems to me that you are creating an infinite loop, could you indicate what your objective is, what is the behavior you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that javascript runs asynchronously. So, signals and slots dont work as they do in C++.  They fire along with the other code, not sequentially. This makes them an unrealiable Intermediary for logical processing since the order that events can happen can vary.

Instead,

Use property bindings for this one by setting a property  such as currentIndex  to another property created using  `property var <my property>` and  `currentIndex: <my property>`

Then you can change the value of currentIndex by setting `<my property>` without disrupting the flow of things.

```
    Tumbler {
            id: firstTumbler
            model: 10
            anchors.left: parent.left
        } 


       /* Edit in response to comment #1 
        */

     property bool followFirst: testCheckbox.checked


       /* end of Edit in response to comment #1 */

        Tumbler {
            id: secondTumbler
            model: 10


            /* modify the property of currentIndex  by changing this variable which will be bound to the currentIndex property */
            property var m_index: 0


            anchors.right: parent.right


           /* conditional assignment for currentIndex -- do not set currentIndex directly or this will disappear.. 
  instead set secondTumbler.m_index */
            currentIndex: testCheckBox.checked === true ?    firstTumbler.currentIndex : m_index

            /* ensures that changing the currentIndex does not change the     actual property, but instead changes m_index which will be bound to that property */
            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                   m_index = currentIndex;




                  /* Edit in response to comment #1 
                  */

                   if (followFirst) { testCheckBox.checked = false }

                  /* end of Edit in response to comment #1 */
            }
        }
```

this will allow the chckbox to change state along with the tumbler without running into state conflicts arising from the current index changing.

Comment: Thank you Mike. What about changing the CheckBox.checked status using secondTumbler? So that secondTumbler follows firstTumbler when CheckBox.checked = true but as soon as user grabs secondTumbler the CheckBox.checked will be false?

Comment: just define a `property  bool followFirst: CheckBox.checked`   and then add to `onCurrentIndexChanged`   `if (followFirst) { CheckBox.checked = false; }`

Comment: You think about QML in the same way you write the description of in plain English... I know ... crazy huh?